# Godot - Animation not found

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm starting with the animations,
I have a character with movement animations for right, left and up
When uploading, the character performs the animation correctly, but on the console I get an error: "play: Animation not found: Run_Up"
error :"play: Animation not found: Idle_Up"

the error starts to come out, when I'm going up.
it stops when i go anywhere else

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVgL4.png)

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDKz5.png)

[Animations list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx09K.png)

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xM8J.png)

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var VELOCIDAD_MAXIMA = 100
var ACELERACION = 350
var FRICCION = 850

enum {
    RUN,
    PUSH
}

onready var animation_player = $AnimationPlayer

export var velocidad = Vector2.ZERO#(0, 0) 
export var direccion_vector = Vector2.DOWN#(0, 1)
export var direccion = Vector2.ZERO#(0, 0)
export var push_finished = false

var estado = RUN

var targets = []

func run_state(delta):
    var input_vector = Vector2.ZERO

    input_vector.x = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    input_vector.y = Input.get_action_strength("ui_down") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_up")
    input_vector = input_vector.normalized()
    
    if input_vector != Vector2.ZERO:
        direccion_vector = input_vector
        velocidad = velocidad.move_toward(input_vector * VELOCIDAD_MAXIMA, ACELERACION * delta)
        _play_animation("Run")
    #Si el usuario no esta tocando al personaje
    
    elif velocidad.length() == 0 && Input.is_action_pressed("action"):
        _play_animation("Push")
        if $RayCast2D.is_colliding():
            push_finished = false
            estado = PUSH
    
    else:
        velocidad = velocidad.move_toward(input_vector * VELOCIDAD_MAXIMA, FRICCION * delta)
        _play_animation("Idle")
    
    velocidad = move_and_slide(velocidad)
    
func push_state(_delta):
    var collider = $RayCast2D.get_collider()
    collider._on_interact($RayCast2D.rotation_degrees)
    
    if collider:
        estado = RUN
    velocidad = move_and_slide(velocidad)

func animation_finished():  
    if !Input.is_action_pressed("action"):
        estado = RUN
        velocidad = Vector2.ZERO
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    match estado:
        RUN:
            run_state(delta)
        PUSH:
            push_state(delta)
        
func _play_animation(animation_type: String) -> void:
    var animation_name = animation_type + "_" + _get_direction_string(direccion_vector.angle())
    
    if animation_name != animation_player.current_animation:
        animation_player.stop(true)
    
    animation_player.play(animation_name)

func _get_direction_string(angle: float) -> String:
    var angle_deg = round(rad2deg(angle))

    #glanced up
    if angle_deg == -90:
        $RayCast2D.rotation_degrees = 180
        return "Up"

    #glanced down
    if angle_deg == 90:
        $RayCast2D.rotation_degrees = 0
        return "Right"

    #glanced left
    if angle_deg == 180:
        $RayCast2D.rotation_degrees = 90
        return "Left"
    
    #glanced right
    if angle_deg == 0:
        $RayCast2D.rotation_degrees = -90
        return "Right"
    
    return "Right"
```

Comment: That is odd. You might have stumbled upon a bug. What version of Godot are you using? Does reloading the project solve it? Edit: if it does not, consider reproducing the problem in a new project with just the minimum necessary to do so. And also sharing it, for testing.

Comment: godot engine v3.4.4.stable.official[419e713a2] steam, try to reload the project, and still get the same error.
I will try to create a new project with the necessary methods to test

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error
apparently there was another character outside the scene that was causing conflict, since he had other types of animations
I deleted that character and it was solved